# How to fetch value of a bean variable inside the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, conditional-operator

I have use case where in I want to declare a bean which gets initialised at app start up and later I want to use the variable of the bean on a conditional expression
Below is the code snippet

```
// This is the bean I am declaring
@Configuration
public class ABCConfiguration {
    @Bean(name="mybean")
    public ABCConfig abcConfig() {
                // ABCFunction() is a function which returns true/false
        ABCConfig config = new ABCConfig(ABCFunction());
        return config;
        
    }

}
```

```
public class ABCConfig {

    private boolean isXYZ;

    public DRConfig(boolean isXYZ) {
        this.isXYZ = isXYZ;
    }

    public boolean isXYZ() {
        return isXYZ;
    }
}
```

Now I want use value of variable isXYZ inside my application through the already registered bean
on a conditional expression. This is how I am trying right now.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${mybean.isXYZ()} == true")
```

But I am getting the below error
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'

Answer (score 0):

base on this arthicle you can get value of @Bean with several methods one of them is :

[Understanding getBean() in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-getbean)

```java
@Configuration
class AnnotationConfig {

    @Bean(name = {"tiger", "kitty"})
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    Tiger getTiger(String name) {
        return new Tiger(name);
    }

    @Bean(name = "lion")
    Lion getLion() {
        return new Lion("Hardcoded lion name");
    }

    interface Animal {}
}
```

```java
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext context;

 Tiger tiger = (Tiger) context.getBean("lion");
```

Comment: I want to use it in a conditional expression on a class. This works when we want to access bean variable in application logic